# How to get the current values of the state when the values have to go through many different components?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props, react-state

Within my folder templates/ I have a subfolder called /components/.
Within /components/ there are two more folders, /atoms/ & /molecules/

Let's say within my /atoms/ folder I would have:

```
Greetings.jsx  <p> Hello {this.props.userName} </p>
Link.jsx: <a href="this.props.link"> Click this link to head to your profile. </a>
```

Within my /molecules/ folder:

```
HelloBase.jsx <Greetings {...this.props}/> <Link {...this.props}/>
```

Of course with some more logic, apart from this, I would then get the properties userName & link out of the current state and this would render something like:

```
Hello Bob. Click this link to head to your profile.
```

Now let's say I want to add another layer to it, instead of rendering the molecules component on the UI, I want to render something called Hello.jsx which is located within the templates/ folder, outside of the /components/ folder. 
If I remember correctly (and I just tested it), in my Hello.jsx file it would look like this

```
<HelloBase />
```

which will not get the properties out of the current state, even if I attach another {...this.props} into it.

I've tried adding the following within my /atom/ files Greetings.jsx & Link.jsx

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName: '',
      link: '',
    };
  }
```

then changing the /atom/ files logic from `{this.props.userName}` & `{this.props.link}`
to `{this.state.userName}` & `{this.state.link}`

then changing the /molecule/ files logic from `{...this.props}` to `{...this.state}`

then adding to the template/ file `{...this.props}`

It still won't get the current value out of the state.

To Summarize, I want to get specific values out of the current state from:
the atom files to the molecule file to the template file. The template file will be rendered to the UI in the end

```
template
-Hello.jsx
-components
--atoms
---Greetings.jsx
---Link.jsx
--molecules
---HelloBase.jsx
```

If anything doesn't make sense here, I am happy to explain my situation further or display the code somewhere more visually appealing.

Comment: You should use React's Context API in such scenarios.

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: There are many ways: You can either use React's Context API. Or you can use Redux or Flux. If the components are connected with a parent/child relation, then you can create a state in the top level parent and create a function in the same component to change the state. Then you can pass down the newly created function as a prop to each child in hierarchy. And then you can call that function anytime from any component and it will rerender the whole tree.

Comment: Thanks for the help!